# Google Compute Engine - DNS Forwarder / Nameserver

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup a Ubuntu 14.04 instance in GCE and in doing so I need to setup the server to resolve some dns queries for an internal custom domain name that sits in our internal network on the other end of a VPN.

Every attempt to assign a name server gets overwritten by the GCE DHCP settings.

I have tried to assign a name-server to /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.conf and in doing so assigns the nameserver in the resolv.conf file, but it still does not resolve the internal domain correctly, always trying to resolve against Google's servers.
I also attempted to add a name server and domain name to the dhclient.conf file, but it doesn't seem to make any difference to changing these values in the local dhcp file.

Is there a way to go about setting an additional DNS forwarder in an ubuntu instance?

Comment: I have resolved the issue and this question can now be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior and the workaround are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#internal_dns_and_resolvconf), ¨resolv.conf¨ gets indeed reverted by DHCP. The workaround is to modify the DHCP client [policy to pre-append](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf) the IPs (/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf).